# Android layout-sw600dp not working with 8" Galaxy Tab

Tags: android-layout, android

I am working on a project which has to work on both 7" and 8" tabs in Landscape mode. I have created the activitys inside the layout-sw600dp folder. The UI looks perfect on Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7" screen. But the same activity file is completely messed up in an  Samsung Galaxy Tab 3 8" tablet.

How can I create a activity xml file that works both on 7" and 8" tabs?

Answer (score 6):

The size of the device screen in Density-Independent pixels (dp) is related to the physical pixels (px) and the screen density (dpi).
The formula is: dp = px / (dpi / 160)

If I've done my research right:

A Tab2 7 inch has a screen density of 170dpi and a resolution of 1024 x 600. Using the above formula, the screen is 963dp x 564dp.

A Tab3 8 inch has a screen density of 189dpi and a resolution of 1280 x 800. Using the above formula, the screen is 1083dp x 677dp.

Your layout in 'layout-sw600dp' is used where the shortest width is at least 600dp. So I would expect it to be used for the Tab3 but not for the Tab2 (because 564dp doesn't cut it). For the Tab2, I'm guessing either it's taking the layout from your default 'layout' folder or some other layout folder that it qualifies for.

It's up to you how to deal with this. You could change 'layout-sw600dp' to something like 'layout-sw550dp' which would load the same layout for both devices. Or create a 'layout-sw500dp' in addition to 'layout-sw600dp' containing a slightly adjusted layout for the slightly smaller screen.